# msys2: Installing a python package fails

Tags: python, windows, msys2

I run msys2 via PyCharm on MS-Windows.

I try to run this command:

```
C:\msys32\usr\bin\python3.exe -m pip install -e git+https://source.example.com/repos/myapp#egg=myapp
```

I get this output:

```
     15 [main] python3 5640 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by '_bz2.cpython-36m.dll' (0x5A0000) is already occupied
Obtaining myapp from git+https://source.example.com/repos/myapp#egg=myapp
  Cloning https://source.example.com/repos/myapp to ./src/myapp
      9 [main] python3 7008 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by '_bz2.cpython-36m.dll' (0x5A0000) is already occupied
  Error [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable while executing command git clone -q https://source.example.com/repos/myapp "/c/Users/tguettler/PycharmProjects/myproject/src/myapp"
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable


Process finished with exit code 1
```

What could be wrong?

Accessing the URL via web browser works fine.

Roughly the same happens, if I run this command:

```
$ pip install cx_freeze
     16 [main] python3 5748 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by '_bz2.cpython-36m.dll' (0x390000) is already occupied
Collecting cx_freeze
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/16/eab51d6571dfec2554248cb027c51babd04d97f594ab6359e0707361297d/cx_Freeze-5.1.1.tar.gz
     10 [main] python3 2652 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by '_bz2.cpython-36m.dll' (0x390000) is already occupied
    Error [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable while executing command python setup.py egg_info
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I solved it this way:

```
c:\msys32\usr\bin\dash c:\msys32\usr\bin\rebaseall -v
```

Above line was executed in the ms-dos terminal.

Now it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

When you are running pip you just specify the package name, not the URL that the package is located at. E.g.

```
pip install package-name
```

Also, most people run it straight from the command line, rather than through PyCharm

Comment: I use `pip install -e git+https://source.example.com/repos/myapp#egg=myapp` since ages on linux. The package is not on the official pypi and not on our internal pypi server.